# how to save a file in http server using jsf?

Tags: java, tomcat

```
String urlPath = "http://hostname:portno/filepath.pdf";
            url = new URL(urlPath);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            OutputStream outStream = conn.getOutputStream();
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(outStream);
            if (byteContent != null && byteContent.length > 0) {
                out.write(byteContent);
                byteLength = byteContent.length;
            }
```

this code doesn't give any exception but file is not created in my tomcat location

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to write files to tomcat. You are making an HTTP request which sends the bytes to the server.

You should create a `FileOutputStream(..)` and write the bytes there instead. This is in case your code is running in Tomcat.

If your code is a separate application, you need to create a servlet that can handle the incoming request and save the file. No direct way to simply push files to the server (and for the better - otherwise everyone will be uploading files)

Answer (score 0):

apache commons-fileupload

```
  FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    Iterator<FileItem> iterator = items.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        FileItem item = iterator.next();
        if(!item.isFormField()) {
            File uploadedFile = new File("fullPathToFile");
            System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            item.write(uploadedFile);                                        
        }
    }
```